# Jquery update rows in database in real time

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have a MySQL database with a number of rows in it that updates frequently. What i want to happen is if a user opens a webpage and there are 78 rows, then there will be a number in the middle of the page that says 0, but if the number of rows increases while the user is on that webpage then the number in the middle of the page will increase by the number of rows in the database every time a new row is added, so if the user is on the page and after 20 seconds there are 81 rows, then it will show a number 3 in the middle of the page. I have no experience in Ajax so any help will be appreciated. I'm using PHP and a mysql database

Thanks,

Comment: You can use Jquery with ajax to check the number of fields updated and can give a button to the user to reload the page if user wish to reload for your reference you can see thi link http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/, See the last example for more precise help

Comment: what i would do, is get number of rows from db on page load. counter set to 0.
then run a timer in jquery to check num of rows every so many seconds
and compare it to the initial num of rows -> update counter if needed - all in jquery

Comment: This is not a task, where php is good at. Your goal can be archived with ajax and polling, but if you expect an increasing number of visitors, this is not a fitting technology. That is an scenario where node.js fits in - because it could handle long-running connections to the server. A side-effect of this is, that a client gets informed about an update in-time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url : "filename.php,
           data: data-here,
           success: function(return){
                // Do anything here 
               }
           });
</script>
```

In the data, just send the value you want to send to php file

Comment: I did that, but it doesn't update in real time. The page has to be refreshed to update the number. Is there any was i could loop the PHP function so that the number would update dynamically?